# saveEventually cause stackoverflow crash

Tags: android, parse-platform

I'm using parse 1.5.1 sdk for Android and all just worked well till recent.
We did some table cleaning on our parse server database before going to production and ever since we are getting a stackoverflow crash every time we try to make 'saveEventually' to a specific table.

It looks like some kind of recursive happens on parse (by looking on the logs) android code.

Any clue what can fix it? (by the way, when using 'saveInBackground' it is working well)

Here is the stacktrace:

0
java.lang.StackOverflowError
1
at java.lang.ref.FinalizerReference.add(FinalizerReference.java:48)
2
at java.security.MessageDigestSpi.(MessageDigestSpi.java:30)
3
at java.security.MessageDigest.(MessageDigest.java:69)
4
at org.apache.harmony.xnet.provider.jsse.OpenSSLMessageDigestJDK.(OpenSSLMessageDigestJDK.java:53)
5
at org.apache.harmony.xnet.provider.jsse.OpenSSLMessageDigestJDK.(OpenSSLMessageDigestJDK.java:25)
6
at org.apache.harmony.xnet.provider.jsse.OpenSSLMessageDigestJDK$MD5.(OpenSSLMessageDigestJDK.java:119)
7
at java.lang.Class.newInstanceImpl(Native Method)
8
at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:1319)
9
at java.security.Provider$Service.newInstance(Provider.java:989)
10
at org.apache.harmony.security.fortress.Engine.getInstance(Engine.java:155)
11
at java.security.MessageDigest.getInstance(MessageDigest.java:91)
12
at com.parse.codec.digest.DigestUtils.getDigest(DigestUtils.java:88)
13
at com.parse.codec.digest.DigestUtils.getMd5Digest(DigestUtils.java:102)
14
at com.parse.codec.digest.DigestUtils.md5(DigestUtils.java:166)
15
at com.parse.codec.digest.DigestUtils.md5(DigestUtils.java:191)
16
at com.parse.codec.digest.DigestUtils.md5Hex(DigestUtils.java:227)
17
at com.parse.ParseJSONCacheItem.(ParseJSONCacheItem.java:16)
18
at com.parse.ParseObject.checkForChangesToMutableContainer(ParseObject.java:1074)
19
at com.parse.ParseObject.checkForChangesToMutableContainers(ParseObject.java:1096)
20
at com.parse.ParseObject.isDirty(ParseObject.java:997)
21
at com.parse.ParseUser.isDirty(ParseUser.java:95)
22
at com.parse.ParseObject.isDirty(ParseObject.java:992)
23
at com.parse.ParseObject.findUnsavedChildren(ParseObject.java:1178)
24
at com.parse.ParseObject.findUnsavedChildren(ParseObject.java:1168)
25
at com.parse.ParseObject.findUnsavedChildren(ParseObject.java:1174)
26
at com.parse.ParseObject.hasDirtyChildren(ParseObject.java:980)
27
at com.parse.ParseObject.isDirty(ParseObject.java:998)
28
at com.parse.ParseObject.isDirty(ParseObject.java:992)
29
at com.parse.ParseObject.findUnsavedChildren(ParseObject.java:1178)
30
at com.parse.ParseObject.findUnsavedChildren(ParseObject.java:1174)
31
at com.parse.ParseObject.hasDirtyChildren(ParseObject.java:980)
32
at com.parse.ParseObject.isDirty(ParseObject.java:998)
33
at com.parse.ParseObject.isDirty(ParseObject.java:992)
34
at com.parse.ParseObject.findUnsavedChildren(ParseObject.java:1178)
35
at com.parse.ParseObject.findUnsavedChildren(ParseObject.java:1168)
36
at com.parse.ParseObject.findUnsavedChildren(ParseObject.java:1174)
37
at com.parse.ParseObject.hasDirtyChildren(ParseObject.java:980)
38
at com.parse.ParseObject.isDirty(ParseObject.java:998)
39
at com.parse.ParseObject.isDirty(ParseObject.java:992)
40
at com.parse.ParseObject.findUnsavedChildren(ParseObject.java:1178)
41
at com.parse.ParseObject.findUnsavedChildren(ParseObject.java:1174)
42
at com.parse.ParseObject.hasDirtyChildren(ParseObject.java:980)
43
at com.parse.ParseObject.isDirty(ParseObject.java:998)
44
at com.parse.ParseObject.isDirty(ParseObject.java:992)
45
at com.parse.ParseObject.findUnsavedChildren(ParseObject.java:1178)
46
at com.parse.ParseObject.findUnsavedChildren(ParseObject.java:1168)
47
at com.parse.ParseObject.findUnsavedChildren(ParseObject.java:1174)
48
at com.parse.ParseObject.hasDirtyChildren(ParseObject.java:980)
49
at com.parse.ParseObject.isDirty(ParseObject.java:998)
50
at com.parse.ParseObject.isDirty(ParseObject.java:992)

...
...
...

540 
at com.parse.ParseObject.findUnsavedChildren(ParseObject.java:1178)
541 
at com.parse.ParseObject.findUnsavedChildren(ParseObject.java:1168)
542 
at com.parse.ParseObject.findUnsavedChildren(ParseObject.java:1174)
543 
at com.parse.ParseObject.hasDirtyChildren(ParseObject.java:980)
544 
at com.parse.ParseObject.isDirty(ParseObject.java:998)
545 
at com.parse.ParseObject.isDirty(ParseObject.java:992)
546 
at com.parse.ParseObject.findUnsavedChildren(ParseObject.java:1178)
547 
at com.parse.ParseObject.findUnsavedChildren(ParseObject.java:1174)
548 
at com.parse.ParseObject.saveEventually(ParseObject.java:1559)
549 
at com.sheep.ag.activities.GroupSettingsActivity.saveDataToParse(GroupSettingsActivity.java:1219)
550 
at com.sheep.ag.activities.GroupSettingsActivity.onPause(GroupSettingsActivity.java:155)
551 
at android.app.Activity.performPause(Activity.java:5304)
552 
at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnPause(Instrumentation.java:1240)
553 
at android.app.ActivityThread.performPauseActivity(ActivityThread.java:2889)
554 
at android.app.ActivityThread.performPauseActivity(ActivityThread.java:2858)
555 
at android.app.ActivityThread.handlePauseActivity(ActivityThread.java:2836)
556 
at android.app.ActivityThread.access$900(ActivityThread.java:140)
557 
at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1254)
558 
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
559 
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
560 
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4921)
561 
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
562 
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
563 
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1027)
564 
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:794)
565 
at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)

Comment: Looks like a cyclic reference, e.g. A-> B -> C -> A -> etc. What is the structure of the objects you're saving?

Comment: Just found out that if a take off the 'Parse.enableLocalDatastore(this);' everything works just fine... (The objects that im trying to save are NOT saved in localdatabase)... i guess that it is some kind of parse sdk bug...

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem when trying to assign a ParseUser to one of the fields of the ParseObject being saved.

When initializing the ParseObject I used "ParseObject.create()". It was fixed when I switched initialized the object doing "new ParseObject()" instead.